# Runtime Error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: windows, ionic2, mean

I got an error of cannot read property 'push' of undefined in ionic2

```
addReview(){

let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddReviewPage);

modal.onDidDismiss(review => {
  if(review){
    this.reviews.push(review);
    this.reviewService.createReview(review);        
  }
});
```

Comment: obvious question.. where is `this.reviews` getting set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to **declare** and **initialize** your `reviews` array as shown below.

```
export class YourPage {

    reviews:any=[];//here is the place

    constructor(){}

    addReview(){
      let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddReviewPage);
      modal.onDidDismiss(review => {
      if(review){
        this.reviews.push(review);
        this.reviewService.createReview(review);        
      }
    });
}
```